# Rename on move with placeholder / wildcard

Tags: files, cp, mv, copy

Lets say I have the following files

```
/home/user/test1.java
/home/user/test2.java
/home/user/test3.java
/home/user/test1.java.orig
/home/user/test2.java.orig
/home/user/test3.java.orig
```

I want the overwrite the files without the `.orig` extension with those files having it, eg `/home/user/test1.java.orig -> /home/user/test1.java` and so on.

Is there some command like the following?

```
mv /home/user/*.orig /home/user/*
```

where I can use the placeholder from the source in the destination definition and where I can specify that I want to overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in /home/usr/* ; do mv "$file" "${file//.orig/}" ; done
```

Should do the trick for you, it loops through all of the files (and directories) in /home/user by using glob expansion, and replaces any instance of the string `.orig` with nothing, so deletes it.

It should be fine so long as you don't have any subdirectories with `.orig` in their name. This will give you some error messages which aren't critical, but may be annoying. To only work on the files which have a `.orig` extension you can insert a conditional check whether the file has the unwanted extension:

```
for file in /home/user/* ; do [[ $file = *.orig ]] && mv "$file" "${file//.orig/}" ; done
```

Comment: For each file that is not an `.orig` file (files that will move to "itself") this will output `mv: ‘/home/user/X.java’ and ‘/home/user/X.java’ are the same file`. Can I suppress this warning?

Comment: You could send STDOUT to `/dev/null` by putting `2> /dev/null` at the end of the command. There's a way to do this without generating the error in the first place though, I'll put together an edit.

Comment: Thank you, also for directories this will output `mv: cannot move ‘/home/user/dir/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘/home/user/dir/’`.

Comment: There's a command that shouldn't give you any errors, so no need to redirect standard out, I've also quoted the file variable expansion, just incase you have files with space in the names.

Comment: Thanks, accepted your answer, yet I will use the method I posted as answer below because it runs recursivly (I have to admit that I forgot to state this in the question). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(find /home/user/* -name "*.orig") ; do mv $file ${file//.orig/} ; done
```

This will only move the files with the given extension, and also runs recursively through subdirectories.

If recursion should be turned off, on can add `-maxdepth 1` to the find command.

Comment: `find` is always handy, it also has a `-exec` option which you could use to do the `mv` command, so you wouldn't need to run a `for` loop. You could also add the `-type f` option to the search part of find to only work on files.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm still a newbie and learn step by step to get better in using Ubuntu :)